# gsutil Crashes on macOS Catalina

Tags: google-cloud-platform, macos-catalina

I need to download a large directory from Google Cloud Platform, which I'd normally use gsutil for.

After upgrading to Catalina (10.15.1) and upgrading everything installed via homebrew, the gsutil utility crashes whenever it's called.

```
chris@cmg-15 ~ % gsutil
/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil: line 223: 23947 Abort trap: 6           "$CLOUDSDK_GSUTIL_PYTHON" $CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_ARGS "${CLOUDSDK_ROOT_DIR}/bin/bootstrapping/gsutil.py" "$@"
```

`python --version` returns Python 3.7.0

I've tried removing gsutil etc via homebrew and installing from [Google's instructions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install) and get the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Appears to be an issues with the way Homebrew is managing the openssl installation.

The recommended fix worked for me:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libcrypto.dylib  /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/local/lib/libssl.dylib
```

source: [Python 3 in macOS Catalina: Fixing the abort trap](https://holgr.com/python-3-in-macos-catalina-fixing-the-abort-trap/)

Comment: Thank you -- this worked for me. Accepted as the answer.

Comment: It almost worked for me. However, I had to change `1.1.1.1d` to `1.1.1.1g` in both lines

Comment: 'g' here too

ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1g/lib/libcrypto.dylib  /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1g/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/local/lib/libssl.dylib